# sourcemap not working on firefox with Webpack on Angular 2 application

Tags: javascript, firefox, typescript, webpack, source-maps

I wanted to use this yeoman generator to create an anuglar 2 application (using Webpack): https://github.com/shibbir/generator-angular2-typescript

But i'm having an issue with sourcemaps. I'm not able to see .ts line numbers on Firefox console. What i see instead is a "link" to something like this: `view-source:http://localhost:3000/app.js line 265 > eval` 
If i click on the line number from the console i get to an error page saying `Cannot GET /app.js%20line%20265%20%3E%20eval` and an alert "The specified line was not found" (which is not surprising since the "file" is only 1 line long).
The same thing happened using this project: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

On Chrome they both work fine and the line numbers on the console point correctly to the .ts file

Looking on the internet i've found there were some bugs on Firefox  with sourcemaps but it was about version 45 or so and it was fixed (using Firefox 49 now)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need **Firefox 50**, and you need to manually enable Sourcemaps.

> At the moment source map support is disabled by default. To enable it, visit `about:config`, find the preference `devtools.sourcemap.locations.enabled` and set it to **true**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Console_messages#Source_maps

Comment: i forgot to mention i opened a ticket on Bugzilla for this https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1309493 I wonder why they didn't post updates on this

Comment: They do have this bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1317962

Then once this issue is resolved, then it will be enabled by default: https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html/issues/1220

Comment: You should maybe note that you have to restart firefox after enabling the feature.

Comment: It's `devtools.source-map.locations.enabled` at least in firefox 54